# How to include .NET Core in my installers (Windows and macOS)

Tags: c++, .net-core, wix, windows-installer

I have a C++ application that relies on .NET Core to interact with a C# assembly. I want my application to work without the need to install other components first, so **I want to include .NET Core in my installers**.

[There are scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) provided by Microsoft but they're intended for CI (they perform a non-admin installation). After installing using the scripts, the `load_hostfxr` function (see [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting#create-a-host-using-nethosth-and-hostfxrh)) is unable to find the installation.

How can I then provide a complete installation of .NET Core? How is the function `load_hostfxr` internally checking if `dotnet` is installed (in both Mac & Win)?

Note: I'm using Wix for the Windows installer and the "Packages" app for the macOS installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved it by using the installers provided by Microsoft.

**macOS**

Included the .NET Core pkg as a "Resource" in the Packages project, then created a post-install script to execute it:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo installer -pkg dotnet-runtime-3.1.10-osx-x64.pkg -target /
```

In this case, .NET Core will be installed silently.

**Windows**

Using Burn, I've created a new Bootstrapper project. The resulting .exe will execute my previous installer (.msi) and also the .NET Core installer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <?include ..\Setup_Custom\Variables.wxi ?>
  <Bundle Name="!(loc.ProductName) $(var.VersionNumber)" Version="$(var.VersionNumber)" Manufacturer="!(loc.ManufacturerName)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" IconSourceFile="Icon.ico">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>
    <WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLicenseRtf" Value="License.rtf" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLogo" Value="Logo.png" />
    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="dotnet3"/>
      <MsiPackage
        Compressed="yes"
        SourceFile="CustomSetup.msi"
        Vital="yes"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
  <Fragment>
    <util:DirectorySearch
      Id="NetCoreInstalled"
      Variable="NetCoreInstalled"
      Path="[ProgramFiles64Folder]dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.10"
      Result="exists" />
    <PackageGroup Id="dotnet3">
      <ExePackage
        Id="dotnet3"
        InstallCondition="NOT NetCoreInstalled"
        DetectCondition="NetCoreInstalled"
        Cache="no"
        Compressed="yes"
        PerMachine="yes"
        Permanent="yes"
        Vital="yes"
        SourceFile="dotnet-runtime-3.1.10-win-x64.exe"
        DownloadUrl="https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/9845b4b0-fb52-48b6-83cf-4c431558c29b/41025de7a76639eeff102410e7015214/dotnet-runtime-3.1.10-win-x64.exe"/>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

In this case, the .NET Core installer UI will be shown.